# how to get facilities of API11, while API10 is installed currently

Tags: android

I am developing a snake and ladder game for Android handsets. Currently I am using Android API Level 10 (2.3.3)

ImageView doesn't support setX, setY till API level 10; this feature's support starts from API level 11. So I want to add that support to API Level 10. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

An API level reflects a version of Android running on a device. You cannot change the version of Android on millions of devices just by asking on StackOverflow. Those device users can upgrade, or they can download a modded ROM for their device that supports API Level 11 or higher.